# $L^p$ spaces are always connected?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, lp-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Is it possible for $L^p_{\mu}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to be disconnected?

**Sketch of Proof**
I assume not since I've heard a folklore that all Banach spaces are homoeomorphic and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (Lebesgue measure) is contractible.

*Maybe I'm wrong since I'm thinking of $\sigma$-finite measures...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every topological vector space (and thus every normed space) is path-connected, and thus connected.

Indeed, let $V$ be a topological vector space (or simply normed space if you want it less general). Then given $v,w \in V$, the map

$$[0,1] \to V: t \mapsto tv+(1-t)w$$ is clearly continuous, showing that $V$ is path-connected.

In particular, $L^p_\mu$ is connected so the answer to your question is always negative, for any measure $\mu$.

Answer (score 3):

All topological vector spaces $V$ are contractible, in particular path connected.
A contraction is given by
$$H : V \times [0,1] \to V, H(v,t) = tv.$$

However, it is not true that all Banach spaces are homoeomorphic. For example, $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ are hoeomorphic iff $n = m$.

Comment: Right; I meant all separable infinite dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block Correct, this is the Anderson–Kadec theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Kadec_theorem

Comment: Super!  Thanks Paul Frost!